# Cassandra rename supercolumn

Tags: cassandra, phpcassa

I am using super column to create chat between two people.

Each chat has it's own row where all of the messages are contained.

And when user wants to delete that chat i would just rename column to something like `old_chat_deleted` and i would create new column family where new chat messages would be stored, but now the problem is how can i rename my old column family?

If that is not possible the only option left is to delete whole cf and create new one with new name, but if chat have `100k+` messages that would probably be very very slow, since i would need to retrieve all data back to my server and then insert it back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming column CF's are not supported out of the box.

You don't need to create a new CF for every chat.
You can create a CF with messages for all chats and include and [indexed column](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/ddl/indexes) identifying the chat session. Or you can use [composite keys](http://xamry.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/composite-keys-in-cassandra/) for the chat records.

Creating a CF for every chat is a bad practice and will severely impact the cassandra performance.